# poweroff/reboot hangs when sddm is logged in

Tags: linux, power-management, systemd, sddm

I am using KDE plasma5 wayland with sddm, and systemd 253.4. sddm starts on tty7, and kde starts on tty2. After logging in to GUI, whenever I tried to poweroff or reboot (terminal or button, through `systemctl`. Suspend is not affected), a wall message "this computer is [operation] NOW!" is displayed and the system hangs indefinitely with it. The goal would be to get rid of this hang when powering off or rebooting.

When the message appears, if switching to tty7 by pressing C-A-F7, the system starts to poweroff/reboot normally. Adding `--no-wall` as suggested [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/archlinux/comments/xi8eap/how_do_i_disable_systemd_wall_message/) to block the wall massage broadcasted by systemd will remove the message, but the system then hangs with a black interface instead of the message, and everything else appears to be the same. If I didn't login with sddm, poweroff/reboot operations won't be interrupted.

I am suspecting if sddm is blocking is blocking the operations somehow, but cannot find methods to solve it. Any help or suggestions to get rid of it would be appreciated.